# BASH - Add new command + run python through that command?

Tags: arguments

Hey guys.
So, I have a Python script. Let's call it "Pythonfile.py" (Wow, I have so much imagination xD)
I would usualy run it by typing in:

```
$ python ~/Desktop/Pythonfile.py -arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now, this is kinda bothering; having to type all the python things. Idealy, I would want to run it like:

```
$ pythonfile -arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This would mean adding a new command to bash. But how? I would guess you should put a file:

```
/usr/bin/pythonfile
```

But what should be inside? I want it to run the original python script, which is located on the desktop - AND WITH THE ARGUMENTS .I'm on Ubuntu 10 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't place the command in `/usr/bin` unless it is meant to be run by all users. Place it in `~/bin` instead, and modify the `PATH` environment variable to search for executables there, by adding this to yout `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

As to the contents of the (now) `~/bin/pythonfile`, you may use:

```
#!/bin/bash
python ~/Desktop/pythonfile.py $*
```

The first line tells `bash` the file is a bash script, and the second line executes the python script.

You can also set `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of the Python script, move the script to `~/bin`, make it executable, and the run it as:

```
$ pythonfile.py -arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Something I like to do with that second option is to add a symbolic link to avoid having to type the `.py` part:

```
$ cd ~/bin
$ ln -s pythonfile.py pythonfile
```